# Mysql table column update issue

Tags: mysql

I am using below query to update a column but not able to update.

```
update table1
 set month_0val = (select v1.sumvalue 
 from ( select r1.reg_id, sum(backbook.bal) as sumvalue
 from  table2 backbook , table3 s , table4 r1
 where month(backbook.Date_AsOf) = month(s.MONTH_AS_OF - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) and year(backbook.Date_AsOf) =  year(s.MONTH_AS_OF - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)  and  backbook.a_region_id = r1.region_code
 and r1.org_id = org_id and  backbook.A_ProdType_Code != 25  and s.SC_ID = sc_id group by backbook.A_Region_ID ) v1
 where v1.reg_id = table1.Region);
```

even the inner query returns result.

Please help.

Comment: Is there any error? It would be more helpful if it is..

Comment: No there is no any error.........

Comment: For more information table1  is of type memory and others are Innodb...

Comment: Both of SELECTs gives you the desired result?

Comment: Yes both are returning desired result............

Comment: If both of your SELECTs returns the result, it should updates all of your records in table1 since you are not using any WHERE condition on the UPDATE query. If it does not, I can only propose you to check table1.month_0val and v1.sumvalue data types. Or even if there are any records in table1.month_0val to begin with.

Comment: You can start your query with begin(), then your query and at the end write commit(); Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1, ( 
            select r1.reg_id, sum(backbook.bal) as sumvalue
            from  table2 backbook , table3 s , table4 r1
            where month(backbook.Date_AsOf) = month(s.MONTH_AS_OF - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
              and year(backbook.Date_AsOf) =  year(s.MONTH_AS_OF - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)  
              and  backbook.a_region_id = r1.region_code
              and r1.org_id = org_id 
              and  backbook.A_ProdType_Code != 25  
              and s.SC_ID = sc_id 
            group by backbook.A_Region_ID 
            ) v1
SET table1.month_0val = v1.sumvalue
WHERE v1.reg_id = table1.Region;
```